# Pandoc in papaja won't decode byte \xc6

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, papaja

I am using `rmarkdown` and `papaja` to build APA style manuscripts.
However, when I try to use font "ć" it won't knit and gives me an error

```
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xc6': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```

This is only true for letters in affiliation and author part, as far as I noticed!

Do you know how I can get arount this problem?

Comment: Is your R Markdown UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#character-encoding

Comment: @crsh: How can I check that?

Comment: @mb21: in Rmarkdown, pandoc is run in the background. I don't know how to edit its code...

Comment: your input file (that you feed to rmarkdown which feeds it on to pandoc) is not UTF-8 encoded... how do you check that? see the link...

Comment: @mb21 I write in RMarkdown file (.Rmd) and then knit the file to .pdf (by pressing a button in RStudio). I don't do it over the command line, so that I would be able to write a code like `iconv -t utf-8 input.txt | pandoc | iconv -f utf-8`. Or maybe I can, but I don't know where...

Comment: try `iconv -t utf-8 file.Rmd > file2.Rmd` or maybe RStudio (or another text editor) has an option to save your file as UTF-8