# Quarto / pandoc: Can't find source of pandoc error -- pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\x93'

Tags: r, rstudio, pandoc, quarto

I'm working on a book project in RStudio (2022.07.2 Build 576) using quarto (v. 1.1.189) and pandoc (v. 2.19.2).
I am compiling only to HTML.

Yesterday, rendering the book failed with the message below, but without any indication where this might be.

```
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\x93': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

(This character seems to be an open 'smart quote', represented in LaTeX by "``")

I've searched for non-ascii characters in all my source files, but find none.

```
> files <- list.files(pattern = "*.qmd")
> for(f in files) {tools::showNonASCIIfile(f)}
> bibs <- list.files("bib", pattern = "*.bib")
> for(f in bibs) {tools::showNonASCIIfile(f)}
> R <- list.files("R", pattern = "*.R", full.names = TRUE)
> for(f in R) {tools::showNonASCIIfile(f)}
```

What else can I do to track down this error?  I tried commenting out all chapters except for `index.qmd`
and get the same result.  I also tried removing nearly all the text from `index.qmd`, same.
Is it possible that quarto has written something evil in a file in `.quarto`?

[pandoc returning "Cannot decode byte '\xf9'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67313824/pandoc-returning-cannot-decode-byte-xf9)
mentions this, but in the context of downloading files from a website.
Another SO query, [Pandoc in papaja won't decode byte \xc6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60432489/pandoc-in-papaja-wont-decode-byte-xc6)
mentions using `iconv` but I have no idea how to use this in RStudio

**Edit**: It was suggested to me that there might be something weird in the `.quarto/_freeze` folder, but I deleted this, and then the entire `.quarto/` folder.  The error still persists.

I still have no idea how to find the source of the problem.

**Update**: I filed this [pandoc issue #8884](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8884#issuecomment-1572249374). It was suggested that I upgrade pandoc to the latest version, 3.1.2, which I did.  The same error continues, but my console shows a bit more detail:

```
processing file: index.qmd
1/6 [unnamed-chunk-1]   
2/6                     
3/6 [unnamed-chunk-2]   


processing file: ./flatland.qmd
1/5                       
2/5 [fig-flatland-spheres]
3/5                       
4/5 [fig-1D-4D]           
5/5                       
4/6                     
5/6 [pollen-eureka-code]
6/6                     
output file: index.knit.md

pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\x93': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

So, the problem seems to stem from `index.qmd`. Yet, if I reduce `index.qmd` to just one line,

```
# Preface {.unnumbered}
```

I still get the same error:

```
Rendering:
[1/1] index.qmd
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\x93': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

Comment: I feel your pain.  Hopefully you'll get good answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Question to self**: Did you check non-ascii in any files *outside* your project folder but imported?

**Ugh**: I had referenced one `.bib` file by its location

```
bibliography:
  - bib/references.bib
  - bib/R-refs.bib
  - bib/packages.bib
  - "C:/Dropbox/localtexmf/bibtex/bib/timeref.bib"
```

That one **did** contain a string using smart-quotes.

Correcting that solved the problem. Still I think `pandoc` could be more helpful, by providing the filename and location where such an error occurs. I filed this issue:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8884